# How to develop javascript massage on My delete button in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5

I have a task to delete button in my laravel application.

This is **My blade file** delete button,

```
<a href="/projects/{{ $project->id }}/tasks/{{ $task->id }}/delete" class="editInline"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>
```

and **TaskController** delete method,

```
public function deleteOneProjectTask($projectId, $taskId)
    {
        DB::table('tasks')
            ->where('project_id', $projectId)
            ->where('id', $taskId)
            ->delete();
 return redirect()->route('projects.show')->with('info', 'Task deleted successfully');
    }
```

and task delete **routes**,

```
Route::delete('projects/{projects}/tasks/{tasks}/delete', [
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\TasksController@deleteOneProjectTask',
]);
```

now I need a confirm alert massage before the delete a task when click delete button. how can I develop it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple add `onclick` event on anchor tag.

```
<a href="/projects/{{ $project->id }}/tasks/{{ $task->id }}/delete" class="editInline" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to want to delete this record?')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>
```

Example:

```html
<a href="/projects/{{ $project->id }}/tasks/{{ $task->id }}/delete" class="editInline" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to want to delete this record?')">DELETE</a>
```

If user Click on `ok` then only your `href` action will be execute.